# Casting a type in a data structure

Tags: java, data-structures, casting

I'm going through my old data structures and would like to make them so that I can cast the type when I make the object, not inside the structure. For instance, I have a linked list that accepts stringNodes (another custom class), but I would like to make it like the java libraries linked list where you define the type stored in the linked list outside of the structure itself. Ex:

```
LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>(20);
```

How would I go about doing that? is there any documentation I could look at to find this out?

Comment: Nope, no documentation at all - this is a top secret hidden Java feature. How did you find this?! (I joke, read the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) - they are great starting points for learning Java).

Comment: Google for "Java generics tutorial". You can do that with basically any Java subject, like "Java collections tutorial", or "Java lambda tutorial", or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called **Generics**.  You can read a tutorial about it here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/